# SQL Server : WITH Clause with two related INSERTS

Tags: sql-server, transactions, insert, common-table-expression

The situation I face is as follows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

WITH denominator AS
(
   Lots of source specific SELECT SQL
),
numerator AS
(
   Lots of source specific SELECT SQL
),
assets AS
(
     Lots of SELECT SQL related to crunching the numerator and denominator datasets to produce a combined dataset
),
summary AS
(
     Lots of SELECT SQL to produce a simple row with summary statistics about the assets virtualized table
)
INSERT INTO tbl_assets 
    (SELECT * FROM assets)

AND

INSERT INTO tbl_summary 
    (SELECT * FROM summary)

COMMIT
```

The only question I have is how do I really do the two inserts in one transaction using a single WITH. This query is actually 100 lines long and I have 100 queries like it to manage, so I really need this to all be in a single runnable SQL script. Everything works perfectly until I do two inserts at once

Comment: You can't. Plain and simple. A cte is like an inline view and the scope is lost after the next statement. In your case the cte stack is out of scope as soon as you insert into tbl_assets. You either need to use temp tables, table variable or recreate the entire cte stack again for the second insert.

Comment: If summary is based entirely on `assets` and everything in `assets` is inserted into `tbl_assets`, you might consider inserting into `tbl_assets` with an output clause (into a table variable), then doing your summary stuff from that table variable.

Comment: You can't, but.. maybe you could use a table variable

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah I think variables/temp tables might be the right solution, but I never used them before. I cannot insert assets before summary due to table relationships... Another thing to consider: I said I would have 100 of these to manage... in reality, the only SQL that changes is the numerator and denominator sections across all 100. So I really am looking for the right way to do this, I think it may involve stored procedures, which I've never used either.

Comment: If someone can provide an example of how to do this the right and optimum way inside MSSQL it would be appreciated. Stored procedures/functions, plus temp/variable tables, plus the fact I have 100 of these to manage and only 1/2 of the SQL will be changing (the numerator and denominator), plus the fact that I'm better with MySQL... there are a lot of unknowns and I could use a go by.